# C++ char array concatenation

Tags: c++, string, char, assertion, strcat

I'm trying to overload the plus sign to concatenate two strings, but I keep getting an error.

VS 2010 gives an **assertion failed** message : "Expression: (L "Buffer is too small" && 0)" ; **File:** f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\tcscat_s.inl ; **Line:** 42 .

What do you think is wrong with my code?

```
#include "stdafx.h"

class MyString{
    int l;  // the length of the array pointed by buf
    char *buf; //pointer to a char array
public:
        ...
    MyString(char *);
    friend MyString operator+(MyString &,MyString &);
        ...
};

MyString::MyString(char *p)
{
    buf=new char[strlen(p)+1];
    strcpy_s(buf,strlen(p)+1,p);
    l=strlen(p)+1;
}

MyString operator+(const MyString &a,const MyString &b)
{
    MyString result("");
    result.l=a.l+b.l;
    delete[] result.buf;
    result.buf=new char[result.l+1];
    result.buf[0]='\0';
    strcat_s(result.buf,result.l+1,a.buf);
    strcat_s(result.buf,result.l+1,b.buf);
    return result;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    MyString a("hello"),b("world"),c("");
    c=a+b;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

It work now! Thank you everyone!

Comment: Why do you set the first char in result.buf to the null character?  strcat_s may think that is the end of the buffer.

Comment: because strcat_s concatenates at the end of a string where it finds '\0'.

Comment: This question has been edited so as to include the fixes proposed by the accepted answer. That makes the answer somewhat meaningless. How can this ever be useful to future readers?

Comment: The question also includes the previous versions of the code... click on "edited 8 hours ago".

Comment: Now that it works, let me suggest an optimization. Version 1: add a (possible private) ctor that takes two strings and concatenates them, and then just use that ctor in operator + (effectively moving the concatenation code into the ctor). Version 2: add a (private) ctor that does not initialize the object, and use that in operator + (leaving the concatenation code in operator +). -- That way you safe one new, one delete and one call to strcpy_s. Also move the `l=strlen(p)+1;` call in the `char*` ctor before the other 2 calls and then use `l` instead of `strlen` in the next 2 lines.

Comment: And of course the `char*` ctor should really be a `const char*` ctor. And maybe make yourself acquainted with initializer-lists. For this class it doesn't really matter if you use them or not, but if the member variables that need to be initialized in the ctor are class-types themselves, then it can be faster to initialize them in the initializer-list instead of assigning them later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In operator+ the variable "MyString result" was declared on the stack and it was subsequently returned by reference, which was bad.

Then the OP was edited. The variable "result" was no longer declared on the stack, but instead allocated on the heap. However, then there was a memory leak.

The right thing to do here is to return by value and also declare "MyString result" on the stack. Also make sure you have a copy constructor. And a destructor for that matter.

You should also make your constructor takes a "const char*".

Comment: What you say is very interesting, and that's what I will do, but do you know what's wrong with `strcat_s(result->buf,strlen(a.buf),a.buf);` ?

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> strcat_s(result->buf,strlen(a.buf),a.buf);
> strcat_s(result->buf,strlen(b.buf),b.buf);
> ```

The second parameter of `strcat_s` is the size of the destination buffer, not the size of the string that shall be appended.
So you need to change that to

```
strcat_s(result->buf,result->l+1,a.buf);
strcat_s(result->buf,result->l+1,b.buf);
```

The rest of the operator + implementation is broken as well, as was already noted by others. Newing up an Instance and then returning it by value is nonsense. Just instantiate the result on the stack and return by value.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `result.buf=new char[result.l+1];` to allow for the null character.

Comment: that gives the same assertion failed message; I thought '\0' at the end of a.buf is replaced by the first character in b.buf